# Why wont my images show up in my traffic light in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to create a traffic light that changes whenever the user presses the button. However, whenever I try to run the code, a square with a black 'X' shows up with the button instead. Something must be wrong with my images or something along those lines and without getting this problem fixed, I will not be able to see how well my code works. The images are saved in the same folder as the code as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="none" src = "red.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change lights</button>

<script>
var lights = ["orange.jpg", "green.jpg", "orange.jpg", "red.jpg"];
var counter = 0
function changelight(){
document.getElementById("none").src=lights[counter]
      counter = counter + 1
       if(counter > 3) {
        counter = 0;
        }
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the images in the same folder as the HTML?

Comment: @Liam "The images are saved in the same folder as the code as well"

Comment: Look at the F12 console in the browser for errors.

Comment: `counter = counter + 1` can be simplified to `counter++`

Comment: Have you checked the F12 Network tab for an image not being able to be found in the directory?

Comment: the id is none, there's no element to be selected ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function's name is `changelight` but you call it as `changeLights()`

Comment: probably a typo, why would he get the "broken image" image?

Comment: @Jaro Until I get more details I point out the obvious stuff.

Answer (score -2):

you have declared the javascript function as "changelight()" in the 11th line :-

```
function changelight()
```

But you have used named the function as "changeLights()" in the 6th line :-

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change lights</button>
```

name the function as same as it is being declared. Thank YOu..!!

Comment: How is this answer any different than the other one that says the same thing, and was posted a half an hour earlier?

Comment: sorry, i have not gone through that.....!! seen the question & answered accordingly..!!